# Is it possible to use syntax highlighting on Github Flavored Markdown without fencing?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Syntax highlighting works fine (on Github):

````
```html
<script scr='/foo.js'>
```
````

Is it possible to use syntax highlighting ***without*** fencing?

```
For example, `<script scr='/foo.js'>`
```

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear from your question whether you want inline syntax highlighting on the `github.com` site itself, or whether you want inline syntax highlighting on an arbitrary site that happens to support the github variant of markdown.

If it's the former, then, no, `github.com` won't currently add syntax highlighting to inline code.

If it's the latter, then it depends on the particular tool that you're using to convert markdown to HTML. [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org), for example *does* support syntax highlighting for inline code.

Comment: I wanted to use it on github.com, but the extra info is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have syntax highlighting on github with inline code blocks or space-indenting, only with fencing.

Comment: You might add that the reason is that there is no way to identify the language of the code block on anything except fenced code blocks. Yes, some highlighting scripts can guess, but that is not always reliable -- especially on short code snippets found in inline code blocks.

Comment: Why can't there be a way to identify the language? Like: `ruby\`puts :OK\``